# Can I sort the songs in a playlist on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sort, playlist

Is it possible to change the order of songs in a playlist on the iPhone?  For example, if they are originally sorted alphabetically by "Artist", can I change the song order of the playlist so that the songs are sorted by "Date Added"?

Answer (score 2):

Im sorry, but in my knowlege there is no way to change the sorting in the way that you describe. The only close solution that i know of would be to edit the playlist manually, by pressing the "Edit" button in the top of the playlist, press and hold the three gray stripes on the right side of a chosen song title, and move it to its intended location within the playlist.

Answer (score 1):

There is a round about way to do this.  First, go to the playlist you want to sort and sort it.  Next crate a new playlist.  Leave it titled as playlist for now.  Go back to your original playlist and drag the now sorted songs to the newly created playlist.  Once that's done, the songs will be in the new playlist in the order you wanted them.  Go ahead and delete you original playlist, then rename the new one to the name of the original playlist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, and it worked for me:

In your computer's iTunes, open up your iPod and click "add playlist." It brings you to the screen with the changeable Playlist title and a bunch of album covers on the left of the screen, y'know what I mean? Under the changeable Playlist title is a Sort By dropdown menu. I want my songs ordered from most recently downloaded to oldest, so I chose Date Added. I see there's also an Artist option.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get alot of these things to work because I added all my songs at once to my iPhone so I:

1. Put the playlist in the order I wanted by clicking Date Added or Purchased Date
2. Clicked on the smart playlist
3. File>Library>Export Playlist
4. File>Library>Import Playlist.
   (The playlist will be imported into your iTunes library at the bottom under Playlists in your sidebar.)
5. Once it's in your library, you can drag it to your iPhone/iPod
   (It will be in the order it was in when you exported the playlist)

Answer (score 0):

I went under the info of all the songs I wanted and set their album name to a word I felt fit them so they would all be under one album I could play. Then to get the order I wanted I went under info once more pressing "more info" go to the "info" tab and three down to the right you will see the option of "track number". Set in the number for what the order is of the song you want to place first out of how many you will have. E.g. "Imagine Dragons. Track Number 1 of 102" Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to playlist
2. Hit edit
3. On the right hand side, you will see three lines, touch them

That will allow you to move the song to any order.

Comment: This isn't sorting but merely re-ordering which is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Open the playlist you want. At the top click edit. Then hold down from the right side and drag where you want.

Answer (score -1):

Click the settings button in the bottom left hand corner next to 'new playlist'. Click 'copy to play order' whilst your phone is plugged in :)

Answer (score -1):

Make a new smart playlist, and set the rule for "Date Added" is after 2013 or whatever date you want.

This will list any songs added after the date you specified, and will auto update. Sync to iPhone.

Comment: Question is how to sort them